# How do you represent a case statement in UML activity diagram?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I am currently creating an activity diagram for a complex logic when I came across a logic there there are several options to choose and the Diamond (Decision node) doesn't seem to be a good way of representing it.

So how do you represent a switch-case statement in UML activity diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision node should be perfect for it. Just use several outgoing transitions with conditions and probably an else transition. If you really like it more you can omit the decision node and just use multiple outgoing transition from the former activity node.

Comment: I used the normal activity mode with multiple outgoing transition. Thanks.